# Given a symplectic manifold, does it make sense to talk about "symplectic Hessian" at a critical point?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

If $f$ is a smooth function on a symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$ we can define its symplectic gradient : this is a vector field $X_f$ such that $\iota_{X_f} \omega = - df$. My question is the following : consider a critical point of $f$, does it makes sense to talk about "symplectic Hessian" at this point ? If yes, how can we define/compute it ?

Comment: Having used the symplectic structure to obtain a vector field, you can compute its intrinsic derivative at a zero. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462819/what-is-the-meaning-of-dx-p-for-x-a-vector-field-on-a-manifold/1462925#1462925).

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot !

Comment: You're most welcome.